# How to cleanup SCSS in Nextjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sass, next.js

It is many pages and there are some unused. Is there a way to delete all unused by searching the classname? Thank you for help!

Answer (score 0):

Next comes with [PostCSS](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/customizing-postcss-config), you can use it to post process your CSS (SCSS).  PurgeCSS is a [PostCSS](https://purgecss.com/guides/next.html#customize-postcss-configuration-next-js-9-3) plugin that removes unused styles.  Also, some CSS frameworks like tailwind, remove unused styles during the build process.